# Need a Goldilocks regex pattern - not too greedy and not too selfish

Tags: python, regex

I've got a set of strings that might look something like this:

```
lines_ = ["04/04      1,000.00    Some word132:11bdkljas     14235262634235",
          "04/04        500.00    A simpler phrase           19058453049854",
          "04/04  1,000,000.00    Apply//erklj//1324:123"]
```

I'm trying to write a regex that will pull out those first three "elements" of the string. I realize that based on this example, I could simply use `re.split("\s{2,}")` and then just grab the first three elements, but I can't guarantee that the input will always have two or more spaces separating the pieces I want. So I'd rather have a more robust regex to grab it.

I tried using this:

```
r"(\d{2}/\d{2})\s+([\d,]+\.\d\d)\s+(.+)(\s+\d+)"
```

Which works for the first two elements, but not the third since there's no set of digits there. So then I tweaked it to this:

```
r"(\d{2}/\d{2})\s+([\d,]+\.\d\d)\s+(.+)(\s+\d+)?"
```

This works for the third one, but for the first two, it includes that fourth element as part of the third element. So then I tweaked it further to look like this:

```
r"(\d{2}/\d{2})\s+([\d,]+\.\d\d)\s+(.+?)(\s+\d+)?"
```

Thinking that the `?` inside of the `(.+)` would make it less greedy and not gobble up the last element. Instead, it gives me the first letter of the first word in the third element and that's it.

What I would like to end up with is an output like the following:

```
groups_ = [("04/04", "1,000.00", "Some word132:11bdkljas"),
           ("04/04", "500.00", "A simpler phrase"),
           ("04/04", "1,000,000.00", "Apply//erklj//1324:123")]
```

Any advice on what I'm missing in my regex would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this pattern with mg options

```
(\d{2}/\d{2})\s+([\d,]+\.\d\d)\s+(.+?)(?:\s+(\d+)|,|$)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/370)

Answer (score 1):

How does this work for you?

```
import re
lines_ = ["04/04      1,000.00    Some word132:11bdkljas     14235262634235",
          "04/04        500.00    A simpler phrase           19058453049854",
          "04/04  1,000,000.00    Apply//erklj//1324:123"]

for i, line in enumerate(lines_):
    match = re.search(r'''
        (\d\d/\d\d)    # eg: 04/04
        \s+            # one or more spaces
        ([0-9.,]+)     # digits, with commas and decimal points
        \s+            # one or more spaces
        (.*?)          # "everything else" (non-greedy)
        (\s+\d+)?      # ... optionally followed by one or more 
                       # spaces and a bunch of digits
        $              # end of line
    ''', line, re.VERBOSE)

    if match:
        print i, match.groups()
    else:
        print i, None
```

When I run the above I get the following output:

```
0 ('04/04', '1,000.00', 'Some word132:11bdkljas', '     14235262634235')
1 ('04/04', '500.00', 'A simpler phrase', '           19058453049854')
2 ('04/04', '1,000,000.00', 'Apply//erklj//1324:123', None)
```

Comment: Interesting. When I tried this approach (albeit slightly different with regard to the digits with commas and a decimal) it wouldn't even find the third element as seen [here](https://regex101.com/r/hL9nJ7/1).